# Convert byte string to emoji in MySQL

Tags: mysql, utf-8, byte, emoji, utf8mb4

`SELECT BINARY('');` outputs `àÛÕ`.

How to convert the (result) byte string back to an emoticon?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

May be related to the client and mysql version, I just did a test, Sequel Pro is OK

Comment: See "Mojibake" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored